# Redirect from sub-directory to parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect all images that look like this:

http://site.com/subdir/a/b/c/image.jpg

to something like this:

http://site.com/a/b/c/image.jpg

using htaccess rewrite rules. Only `http://site.com/subdir/` is fixed, the rest of the paths are variable (can change).

Basically I want to take out "subdir/" from the path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this : in your `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBasae /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^subdir/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/([\w\d-]+\.[\w]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$3/$4 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/([\w\d-.]+\.[\w]+)/?$ subdir/$1/$2/$3/$4 [L]
```

Comment: Is there no better way to do this for any depth of subfolder? Eg, with wildcard regex?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

use base name instead of the path..